# Find probability that a gap greater than 7 seconds occurs between two consecutive arrivals

Tags: exponential-distribution, operations-research, queueing-theory

So I have a question that basically says:
Customers arrive at a facility at a mean rate of $12$ per minute.
Find the Probability that a gap of greater than $7$ seconds occurs between two consecutive arrivals.

I've started the question and found the mean time between arrivals ($\frac{1}{12}$ minutes $= 5$ seconds).
I also know I need to use the negative exponential distribution, I should use $e^{-λt}$, however, I'm not sure what my $\lambda$ and t value should be.
I think it might be quite simple and I'm overthinking it, any help on how I would obtain $\lambda$ and t would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this can help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PEX-SuftjQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your time was in unit of minutes, your $\lambda$ would be $1/12$, but it is not, right, it is more convenient for us to use seconds and use $\lambda = 0.2$ per second.
Then we use the cumulative distribudion function to find the probability of being outside the interval $[0, 7]$ seconds.
So we may take $1 - $P(being in that interval).

The CDF of $\lambda e^{- \lambda t}$ is $1 - e^{-\lambda t}$.

This equals $1 - CDF[7]$ with the right $\lambda$ (rate, intensity).

$$ 1 - CDF[7] = 1 - (1 - e^{-\lambda 7} )= e^{-0.2*7} = 0.247$$

Comment: Thanks, this was really useful. Just wondering, because I got the same answer just now, would it be easier to do your way or to do: P(t>7)=e^-(12 x (7/60))

Comment: Ok, not is it easier but does this way work as well as yours? (Sorry not sure how to word my question properly)

Comment: Yes, that is equivalent.

Comment: oh ok, great, thanks a lot